# Agglomerative Hierarchical Clustering "complete linkage" as opposed to "single linkage" dendrogram

Tags: hierarchical-clustering

Will any dataset clustered via each of the following methods:

- Agglomerative Hierarchical Clustering using "complete linkage" method
- Agglomerative Hierarchical Clustering using "single linkage" method

have the same dendrogram structure?

If yes, please help prove it or show a contradicting example (if not).

Comment: What do you mean by "dendogram structure"?

Comment: Spelling is dendrogram and it's worth remembering that the root (good word here) is the same as in dendritic or rhododendron. As the dendron root means tree, the word "tree" is redundant.

Comment: @PeterFlom, same hierarchy with only possible difference at heights

Comment: Is this for a class assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will give different dendrograms in most cases. e.g.

```
hc1 <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "single")
plot(hc1)
plot(hc1, hang = -1)

hc2 <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "complete")
plot(hc2)
plot(hc2, hang = -1)
```

Comment: I also got a relevant example via swiss {datasets}

Answer (score 3):

Consider the data set

```
 0
```

run linkage clustering with *any* distance metric or linkage. The result will be the same dendrogram (which consists of a single node, at height infinity).

Alternatively, any data set with two instances will also work.

```
 0
 1
```

Will have a dendrogram merging the two nodes at height 1.

On these data sets, *any* linkage will yield the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Dendrograms are used to visualize clustering results. Single-linkage and complete-linkage clustering may give different results. Hence, the dendrograms can be different too. However, it is quite likely that there are some special cases where the two methods give the same result. Then, also the dendrograms would be the same.

Comment: Can you please help build an example that shows a simple dataset clustered using each of the these methods will give different dendogram?